# Cannot login to X.Org session anymore after some update in Ubuntu 20.04. Wayland works

Tags: nvidia, wayland

Heloo guys,

I am using dual boot window 10 and ubuntu 20.04 LTS with detail as attached picture.
[neofetch system info](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RwfUmIa444KdOmiOztolCtts66CtyTbr/view?usp=sharing)

Everything was fine until couple days ago after updating system I could not login to ubuntu. Actually, I can signin but after that just a purple green and mouse pointer and nothing else.

I googled and found the way to login by selecting gear icon on the right bottom which appear once focus on typing password. I select `Ubuntu on Wayland` and can log in to the ubuntu and happy.

But the problems happend

1. Vokoscreen, kazam... recorded only black screen
2. Default screen recording of ubuntu when pressing `ctrl + shift + alt + R` working fine but `no sound`
3. Online video meeting via zoom still ok but i cannot share my screen due to `wayland`

---

I have tried few ways to fix the problem included disable wayland by edit file `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and deleted the `#` symbol to `uncomment` of `WaylandEnable=false`.
But no luck due to once I login to normal `ubuntu` then just only purple screen and mouse pointer welcome me.

I have checked my nvidia MX150 drivers updated as picture attached
[nvidia drivers](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S5ohY9nxueGmCB1vRjU905buSHfhA8bP/view?usp=sharing)

Please advise!

Comment: Can you login to the default X.Org session after changing the proprietary drivers?

Comment: After doing many command now I have 4 options on `gear` icon as this [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16bbtYgk_E6Ub651SAdxx3yIA78wM6guy/view?usp=sharing)
---
`GNOME` and `Ubuntu on Wayland` can login but both could not using vokoscreen to record screen.
---
I have GNOME X.Org session and could not login too. I have no idea about X.Org session, could you please advise?

Comment: Consider writing the fix as an answer, as that may help future users.

Answer (score 0):

First approach. I have checked and found the reason led to `purple` screen caused by `Pixelsaver` extension. So simple solution is remove that extension by following command on terminal `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver` as instruction in this [link](https://installlion.com/kali/kali/main/g/gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver/uninstall/index.html) then reboot linux and use can log in Ubuntu or `X.Org` as usual

---

Second way is remove and reinstall `Full Gnome Desktop`. At first, Uninstall gnome by command `sudo apt-get remove gnome*` then `reboot`. Once reboot you may get to black screen with error. Please no worry just access to TTY by comand `ctrl + alt + F3` then log in to your account by command. Once login account in TTY command line mode, then you reinstall `FULL GNOME DESKTOP` via `tasksel` as [Link here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa) and once done `reboot` and you can log in to `Ubuntu` as usual.

---

Once log in I suggest you install `gnome-tweaks` and `extenssions` to customize your Desktop working environment.
`Happy Hacking guys`